# Python MultiThreading, Run process background without blocking main thread

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a fast API router with endpoints that accept batch data, I am currently sending to Redis Queue and processing those and writing to parquet files.

```
@router.post("/batch")
async def batch_endpoint(file: UploadFile):
    await process_batch_data(file)
    return {"data": "Successfully processed : " + file.filename



async def process_batch_data(data: UploadFile):
   json_data = await data.read()
   for key, value in json_data:
            try:
                data_str = json.dumps({key: value})
                data = json.dumps({"data": data_str})
                await redis_client.rpush(redis_data_queue_key, data)
```

In this scenario, I am running an asyncio task called process_queued_data() in the **init**.py file.

```
asyncio.create_task(process_queued_data())
```

That process_queued_data is the place where I process the data and writing it into parquet in S3 bucket.

```
async def process_queued_data():

    try:
        while True:
            await asyncio.sleep(5)
            data_queue_length = await redis_client.llen(redis_data_queue_key)
            if data_queue_length > 0:
                batch = await redis_client.lrange(redis_data_queue_key, 0, -1)
                await redis_client.ltrim(redis_data_queue_key, data_queue_length, -1)
                ......do processing and upload to S3
```

My issue is whenever that process_queued_data is running, and when I try to send the file, it hangs until that task is finished. How can I avoid this behavior and accept the data anytime, even when the process_queued_data is running.?